# General description of transition arrows of covering morphisms in family fibrations

Tags: covering-spaces, adjoint-functors

For sets and functions, I think the following data are equivalent:

1. A function $g:A\times B\to B$ such that $(\pi_1,g):A\times B\to A\times B$ is a bijection;
2. a function $A\to \mathrm{Aut}B$.

*Proof.* The first condition is equivalent to $(\pi_1,g)$ having singleton fibers. The fiber of $a,b$ is the intersection $(\left\{ a \right\} \times B)\cap g^{-1} \left\{ b \right\}$, which is exactly the fiber of $g|_{ \left\{ a \right\} \times B}$. Thus $(\pi_1,g)$ is bijective iff all of the restrictions are. These restrictions are precisely the same as a function $A\to \mathrm{Aut}B$. $\square$

Motivated by the transition functions of covering maps, I am hoping for the following statement.

**Tentative proposition.** Let $\Pi_0:\mathsf{Fam}(\mathsf A)\to \mathsf{Set}$ be a fibration of connected components and let $H$ be its right adjoint, the discrete functor. Then the following data are equivalent:

1. An automorphism over $X$ of the projection $X\times HA\to X$;
2. An arrow $g:X\times HA\to HA$ such that $(\pi_1,g):X\times HA\to X\times HA$ is an isomorphism;
3. An arrow $X\to H\mathrm{Aut}A$.

The first two conditions are equivalent in any category, but I'm having trouble exporting of the equivalence of the final two conditions from the category of sets. The distributivity of $\mathsf{Fam}(\mathsf A)$ and $\mathsf{Set}$ along with the adjunction $\Pi_0\dashv H$ and the Cartesian closedness $\mathsf{Set}$ yield natural isomorphisms $$\mathsf{Fam}(\mathsf A)(X\times HA,HA)\cong \mathsf{Fam}(\mathsf A)(X,H\mathrm{End}A),$$ but I also don't know how to get the statement from here.

Is the tentative proposition correct? How can I prove it?

Comment: What is $Fam(A)$ exactly? I am not familiar with the notation.

Comment: @GiorgioMossa sorry. $\mathsf{Fam}(\mathsf A)$ is the free coproduct completion of $\mathsf A$. It's always a fibration over sets assigning to each object the set of its connected components - its coproduct decomposition to objects of $\mathsf{A}$.

Comment: I assume that $A$ is a category, am I correct?

Comment: $\mathsf A$ is a category but $A$ is just an object. You can ignore the notation $\mathsf{Fam}{\mathsf{A}}$ if you want, it's just a category which admits a connected components functor.

Comment: I am not entirely sure how you get the natural isomorphisms from the cartesian closedness could you elaborate a little more? It may help.

Comment: $\begin{aligned}\mathsf{C}(X\times HA,HA) & \cong\mathsf{C}(\coprod_{A}X,HA) & \text{(distributivity)}\\
 & \cong\prod_{A}\mathsf{C}(X,HA)\\
 & \cong\prod_{A}\mathsf{Set}(\Pi_{0}X,A) & (\Pi_{0}\dashv H)\\
 & \cong\mathsf{Set}(\coprod_{A}\Pi_{0}X,A)\\
 & \cong\mathsf{Set}(\Pi_{0}X\times A,A) & \text{(distributivity)}\\
 & \cong\mathsf{Set}(\Pi_{0}X,\mathrm{End}(A)) & \text{(Cartesian closedness)}\\
 & \cong\mathsf{C}(X,H\mathrm{End}(A)) & (\Pi_{0}\dashv H)
\end{aligned}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is true.  Note that $\mathrm{Aut}(A)$ is a triple equalizer of three maps $\mathrm{End}(A) \times \mathrm{End}(A) \to \mathrm{End}(A)$, the composites in both orders and the constant map at $\mathrm{id}_A$.  Since $H$ is a right adjoint, it preserves limits, and in particular this triple equalizer.  Moreover, $\mathrm{End}(A)$ is itself a limit, namely the $A$-fold power of $A$, so $H \mathrm{End}(A)$ is the $A$-fold power of $H A$, which is also the exponential $(H A)^{H A}$ by distributivity of $\mathsf{Fam(A)}$.  Thus $H \mathrm{Aut}(A)$ is the triple equalizer of the corresponding three maps $(H A)^{H A} \times (H A)^{H A} \to (H A)^{H A}$, making it $\mathrm{Aut}(H A)$ (even if we don't assume that $\mathsf{Fam(A)}$ has all limits, it has this one).  Therefore, a map $X \to H \mathrm{Aut}(A)$ is the same as a map $X \to \mathrm{Aut}(H A)$.

The rest of the argument doesn't need $H$ at all, so let $Y = H A$, which might as well be any object of any category such that the triple equalizer $\mathrm{Aut}(Y)$ of the three maps $Y^Y \times Y^Y \to Y^Y$ exists; call these three maps $\mathrm{comp}$, $\mathrm{comp}'$, and $\mathrm{const}_{\mathrm{id}}$.  By the universal property of this triple equalizer, a map $X\to \mathrm{Aut}(Y)$ consists of two maps $\ulcorner f \urcorner X\to Y^Y$ and $\ulcorner g \urcorner X\to Y^Y$ such that $\mathrm{comp}(\ulcorner f \urcorner,\ulcorner g \urcorner) = \mathrm{const_{\mathrm{id}}} = \mathrm{comp}(\ulcorner g \urcorner,\ulcorner f \urcorner)$ (since $\mathrm{comp}(a,b) = \mathrm{comp}(b,a)$ by definition).  By the exponential adjunction $\ulcorner f \urcorner$ and $\ulcorner g \urcorner$ are determined by maps $f:X\times Y \to Y$ and $g:X\times Y\to Y$, and the above equalities translate to say that the composites $X\times Y \xrightarrow{(\mathrm{id},f)} X\times Y \xrightarrow{g} Y$ and $X\times Y \xrightarrow{(\mathrm{id},g)} X\times Y \xrightarrow{f} Y$ are the second projection, or equivalently that $(\mathrm{id},f)$ and $(\mathrm{id},g)$ are inverse isomorphisms, i.e. we have an automorphism of $X\times Y$ in the slice category over $X$, which is your condition 1.

Comment: Wow! I'd have never thought of cutting automorphisms out using a triple equalizer. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm trying to write the details out and I realize I don't understand the end of the proof. What is the object of automorphisms $\mathrm{Aut}(HA)$? Do you define it as the triple equalizer? Why does this limit exist? Finally, how does this object of automorphisms interact with the adjunction to retrieve condition 1 or 2?

Comment: Yes, we define it as the triple equalizer, and the limit exists because we've just shown that $H \mathrm{Aut}(A)$ *is* that limit.  A right adjoint preserves limits even that its codomain is not assumed to have a priori.  I'll edit the answer to add more details about conditions 1 and 2.